# How we can change a string into an integer as well as a float?

Tags: python

```
length = input()
             
area = pow(length,2)
print(area)
```

In this we can give an integer as well as a float number so how we can solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you want to change a string into a float and an integer at once?  What does this have to do with the code?  And what does this have to do with `requests`?  (that's for requests the *library*, not 'requests for help with python')

Comment: You tagged this both Python 2 and 3, but in 3.x this is a TypeError (because input is always a string). It's not clear what you think the problem is.

Comment: well this is my first experience in stack overflow so I didn't knew about this sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is 'how can I cast a str to the best numeric representation', try this:

```py
x = input()
try:
    x = int(x)
except ValueError:
    x = float(x)
```

Comment: Note that this is a duplicate of [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/379966/15452601) in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```py
length = input().strip()
if "." in length:
    length = float(length)
else:
    length = int(length)
area = pow(length, 2)
print(area)
```